# In a 24 hour Soak Test in NonGUI, Jmeter has been running for 12Hrs but after12Hrs it's idle for next 11Hrs, until I hit Enter, Why is this Happening?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I had setup jmeter to run soak test in NON GUI Mode for 24 hours with rampup 0 and loop count 1 with 10 users, but after 12 hours the jmeter has been idle till 11 hours until I went into the command prompt and hit enter for the last 23rd hour,I have even checked the cpu usage , even there it seems there were no actions in the same time from the system , shows it has been idle.
Would be helpful if someone could help me find

-What might have gone wrong

-Where to check for logs and how to understand the log file

Because the same way I have done this test previously, but there was no such idle hours.

Picture of where the jmeter went idle,

[JmeterNonGuiModeCmdPromptPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFX9z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you can reproduce the issue take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and it will show where JMeter hangs
2. Make sure to follow recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article
3. Monitor JMeter JVM metrics using [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to see if Java works as expected when it comes to memory allocation, garbage collection, classes loading/unloading, etc.
4. It might be as trivial as you simply by accident selected something in the command prompt:

   [image]

   [in Windows it pauses the execution completely](https://superuser.com/questions/1442941/windows-10-console-stops-running-if-i-click-in-the-console-window) and the process won't run further until you remove the selection somehow